# Why is Kosher important?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

Why is Kosher important to Jewish people? It is not necessarily healthy food from what I can see.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16041/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/kashrus-explained

Comment: Why the downvote? Just mark as a dupe. Thanks for the links.

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Comment: Why the assumption that it has anything to do with physical health?  It doesn't.

Comment: @DoubleAA Don't think so. That one asks _if_ it's healthy, while this one is almost a continuation of that one. I.e., if it's not about health, why is it important?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I don't believe the question as stated is a dupe:

The laws of Kosher fall into a category of commandments called "chukim". That is, that G-d gave them to us without explaining or giving a reason for them. Through the ages, certain sages wrote many pages giving possible rational explanations, but ultimately, we do not know the reason that *G-d* gave us this commandment (or any of the commandments in this category).

So in short, the reason Kosher is important to the Jewish People? Because G-d said so.